# Using C++ Object as global variable in multiprocessing

Tags: c++, constructor, multiprocessing

I have multi process application. I developed a new c++ class and I want all childs and parent to have their own instance. This object will be only created once for each.

In my code I have global structure which is being used by main and all instances all ready , I want this new object to be accessed globally by instances so I will put it there as well.My structure is like :

```
typedef struct globalvar
{
    worker_t *workers;
    worker_t *curwkr;
    etc.....
    //std::shared_ptr<redisHandler> gredisHandler;
    redisHandler gredisHandler;   <---- New Object (Singleton)
} globalvar_t;
```

And all source files uses it by declaring ;
extern globalvar_t G;

First question : When parent works, the constructor of my new object will be called or not ?

Second question :  If the first question yields that I should use pointers instead and create the object with new operator(or make_shared) after new child spawn , should I pay attention to deleting it when child terminates ? Or OS will take care of it?

Comment: Make your whole structure a singleton class, and initialize everything properly in it's constructor. Try to avoid need for singletons at all.

Comment: And why are you using child processes instead of threads?

Comment: Because I have 32 cores in my hardware , my application handles analysis of 10gbit network traffic per second.

Comment: The OS should share cores for threads as good as for processes, or did I miss something?

Comment: I believe preferring processes over threads is not the point in this question. Processes has their advantages as well as threads. And processes fits better to my application because we don't have so many sharing between our processes.

Comment: Also about core issue; our network card divide the traffic between processes but it can't divide it between threads

Comment: OK, I got it. Anyway, when destructors of singleton objects are called is a topic on it's own. If they're created on the heap (using a pointer and `new`), their destructor will never be called, just the memory is released when the process exits. In case of a statically initialized instance it depends on how the crt code handles calling of destructors of such instances (usually as default handling for `atexit()`.